# Нужна ли запятая перед И (после оборота "без тени улыбки", ...)

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении

```
Он посмотрел на него внимательно, без тени улыбки, и ответил:
```

нужна ли запятая после `без тени улыбки` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**С точки зрения грамматики**, здесь возможны оба решения, то есть  обстоятельства можно считать однородными, раскрывающими одну тему (разделяются запятыми), а можно "без тени улыбки" обособить в качестве дополнительного пояснения.

**С точки зрения структуры предложения и интонации** лучше остановиться на обособленном варианте:

**Он посмотрел на него внимательно, без тени улыбки, и ответил.**

Сравнить: Молча, без тени улыбки, кладет на стол. [Виктор Некрасов. В окопах Сталинграда (1946)].

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение и ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Давайте разбираться. Во-первых, надо понять, корректно ли здесь обособление. Это уточняющий оборот (обстоятельство): посмотрел на него (как?) внимательно, (как именно?) без тени улыбки. С этим-то всё понятно. А сомневаетесь вы, я вижу, в постановке запятой перед союзом *и*. Здесь запятая должна ставиться, так как это границы этого оборота. Схема: [..., оборот, и...]. Союз соединяет однородные сказуемые.

P.S. Здесь нет определения, исправьте заголовок вопроса.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение и ответ!